# Comparisons in return statement

Tags: c, return

Can someone please explain this return statement:

```
return
    (
        a->data == b->data &&
        identicalTrees(a->left, b->left) &&
        identicalTrees(a->right, b->right)
    )
```

Comment: We can't see your code (because you never showed it to us), but from a quick glance this just appears to be checking the data for two nodes, as well as that the left and right subtrees are the same.

Comment: Perhaps this is (a part of) a recursive implementation of `identicalTrees`?

Answer (score 1):

It returns true if the condition in the parentheses is true, where the three-part condition in the parentheses is true if part A is true AND part B is true AND part C is true.

This is a "compressed" expression.  It might be easier to understand if you compare it to this "expanded" version, which does exactly the same thing:

```
if(a->data == b->data &&
    identicalTrees(a->left, b->left) &&
    identicalTrees(a->right, b->right) ) {
        return TRUE;
} else {
        return FALSE;
}
```

More specifically, it looks like it's part of a recursive implementation of a test for "deep" binary tree equality: given pointers to two tree nodes, they point to identical trees if their data is the same, and their left subtrees are the same, and their right subtrees are the same.